# Cyrillic turned to a question mark | Django template HTML metatags

Tags: django, encoding, utf-8, meta-tags

So after deployment my cyrillic description in html metatags turned into question marks. It works fine on my localhost. Im passing html metatags through admin panel as a model so I can change my metatags after deployment easily, in addition to internationalization purposes.

1. Using MySQL
2. Django 2.2.5/Python 3.7.5

***models.py***

```
class Metatags(models.Model):

metatags_en = models.TextField(verbose_name='English Metatags', null=True)
metatags_ru = models.TextField(verbose_name='Russian Metatags', null=True)
metatags_uz = models.TextField(verbose_name='Uzbek Metatags', null=True)
metatags_oz = models.TextField(verbose_name="O'zbek Metatags", null=True)

metatags_en_blog = models.TextField(verbose_name='English Blog Metatags', null=True)
metatags_ru_blog = models.TextField(verbose_name='Russian Blog Metatags', null=True)
metatags_uz_blog = models.TextField(verbose_name='Uzbek Blog Metatags', null=True)
metatags_oz_blog = models.TextField(verbose_name="O'zbek Blog Metatags", null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = _("Metatags")
```

***base.html***

```
{% for x in metatags %}
{% if current_lang == 'en' %}{{x.metatags_en|safe}}
{% elif current_lang == 'ru' %}{{x.metatags_ru|safe}}
{% elif current_lang == 'uz' %}{{x.metatags_uz|safe}}
{% elif current_lang == 'oz' %}{{x.metatags_oz|safe}}
{%else%}{{x.metatags_ru}}
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

***metatags I'm using in cyrillic***

```
    <!-- Primary Russian Meta Tags -->
<meta name="title" content="Лорем ипсум долор">
<meta name="description" content="Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, пер цлита поссит ех.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Лорем ипсум долор сит амет">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days">
<meta name="author" content="Лорем">
```

Answer (score 0):

**So I fixed it!**

**HERE IS THE ANSWER:** 
check the encoding of your db...seems ok? check again.. Now you found out that some tables of yours magically changed their encodings to latin_swedish_ci or smth else?. Now make sure to change the encoding of your db and all tables to "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" and make sure to read [this](https://www.monolune.com/mysql-utf8-charsets-and-collations-explained/) which helped me to realize the answer. This answer is useful for those who cant use emojis on their site too!